# What is the correct way to emplace_back an object into a vector using the range-based for loop? C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have an object that I want to add it to the vector container, but I would like to know is that 2 ways I did the same thing? And what is the correct way to do it?

The reason why I did `m_boid.emplace_back(std::move(bird));` is because `bird` is a range-based-for-loop variable and if I don't use `bird` it will prompt me a warning saying **Unsed variable bird** But program is still able to run as it's not an error.

What is the correct way to emplace_back an object into a vector using the range-based for loop?

Thank you in advance.

```or-tag-here
Boid::Boid(int size)
{
    m_boid.resize(size);  //vector of unique pointer

    for(auto &bird : m_boid)
    {
        //Create an object
        m_obj.reset(new Boid); //unique pointer

            // Add object to vector. Is this 2 below the same thing?
            m_boid.emplace_back(std::move(bird));  //Should I do this?
            m_boid.emplace_back(std::move(m_obj)); //Or should I do this?
    }
}
```

**EDITED. HOW ABOUT THIS? is this ok?**

```or-tag-here
void Boid::initBoid(unsigned int containSize)
{

    m_boid.resize(containSize);

    for(auto &bird : m_boid)
    {
        bird.reset(new Boid);
        bird->createVAO();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add items to a collection in the middle of a range based for. what are you trying to do overall?

Comment: "The reason why I did ... " a warning is just a warning, not an error. It just means the compiler tells you: "I am not sure this is correct, are you?". Using emplace just for that reason doesnt make much sense

Comment: std::vector < std::unique_ptr<Boid> > m_boid ;  is the type for m_boid @Rabbid76

Comment: ...also its not clear why you actually want to achieve. If you iterate over a vector and add another element on each iteration your loop will never end

Comment: @Eubs I see you `resize` before the loop. Did you intend to fill those newly allocated elements with elements, or are you trying to save space at the front of `m_boid`? It looks like you are trying to do the latter.

Comment: I want to add plently of objects into the vector container at the end of the day. For example.. creating 5 objects and putting them in a vector container.

Comment: Maybe you just need `bird.reset(new Boid);` ? (and forget everything else in the loop)

Comment: after you resized, there are already `size` objects in the container, no need to put even more

Comment: I intend to fill my vector with objects the moment the class Boid is created in the main() function. @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Either `resize()` **or** `emplace_back()` but not both I think.

Comment: I want to set the size of my vector so it's determined during compile time. Do you think I should do a push_back() instead? I just thought emplace_back() is C++11 so I could use that @Galik

Comment: a vectors size isnt determined at compile time, even if you call `resize`, maybe you wanted a `std::array` instead

Comment: sorry but your motivations for coding seem a bit odd. My advise: dont use something just because it is C++11, and dont change your code to the worse just because of a compiler warning

Comment: Also by creating `Boid` objects inside the constructor of a `Boid` you are in danger of infinite looping.

Comment: I've made some changes, can you help me to have a look please? Is that better now? @Galik

Comment: [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: Why are you creating the `Boid` objects dynamically at all?  `std:vector<Boid> m_boid;` or `std::array<Boid, size> m_boid;` would create the `Boid` objects automatically when `m_boid`'s size is established.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the correct way to emplace_back an object into a vector using the range-based for loop?

I'd say none. `emplace_back` could invalidate iterators in case of a reallocation, thus you'd get an UB in that case.

Comment: What would you suggest then? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Eubs A simple `for` loop from 0 to `size`?

Comment: Yes I could do that but I'm trying to follow the C++11 standard @skypjack

Comment: @Eubs And why on the Earth you think that a `for` loop isn't standard C++11?

Comment: @Eubs Then put the new elements in a secondary vector and append it to the one you were looping on at the end of the loop. It doesn't make much sense, but if you want to use a range-based for...

Comment: @Eubs range based for loops are *great*. But they are not suitable for *every* situation. "Old-style" for loops are still useful in a number of different situations, and should be used when they are the correct/best solution. Don't use new features *just because they are new and shiny* and you *want* to use them - use them where they *make sense*.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko I'd suggest you to look at the equivalent form of a range-based for loop once more. To invalidate the end iterator isn't exactly what you want while iterating.